# Selenium webdriver using PhantomJs fails to redirect in python

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

i'm tring to automate an oauth2 authentication for a webcrawler in python, i chose to use selenium as a webdriver for doing so.

i won't have root on the machines that i'm going to use so i chose to use phantomjs as this script need to be headless and so i won't be able to install xvfb in these machines.

now i found out that phantomJS have this bug: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10389

and the oauth2 page i need to use have that kind of redirects, the workaround in these page is in javascript and quite useless to me, there is a workaround (considering these premises) or another solution to be completely headless in python?